# Can the current through a connector be higher than the rated current at lower voltages?

Tags: voltage, power, current, dc-motor, connector

I have been searching for **power connectors** for connecting the DC motors in my project. The motors are rated at **24v and 20A stall current**. I find connectors with 5A current rating and 250V max. The motor's input power is *24*20=480W* considering a single motor. A two pin connector with 5A and 250V has *1250W* power. So can it be used to connect the motor? Will the connector handle that much current. Also, since this is my first time figuring out which connectors to use, please tell me the specifications other than voltage and current to consider while choosing the connector.

Comment: Can a fuse handle a higher current at a lower voltage?

Comment: If the limit was watts, they would say 1250W on the connector.

Comment: you are calculating the power dissipation incorrectly ... use contact resistance and current

Comment: @user253751 does that mean I can't pass more current than 5A?

Comment: Well, actually you can, but the connector might overheat or make sparks or something. Might. It means the connector is *designed* for 5A. It's not like it will instantly burst into flames or anything. It does "void the warranty" i.e. it's not the manufacturer's fault if it causes a problem. Realistically, you have to have quite a big overload to melt a connector, but small overloads might shorten the lifetime or something.

Comment: the 250 V rating on the connector is the maximum voltage that can be applied between the connector pins and be guaranteed that arcing will not occur ... it has nothing to do with current carrying capacity

Comment: If I needed to handle 6A peaks for a one-off where consequences of failure weren't that important, then I'd use a 5A connector at a pinch. But 20A is stretching it too far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a connector rated for 5A handles only 5A safely, no matter if the voltage is 1V or 250V. The contact resistance of the connector and the current through it determines the heat dissipated at the connector.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, in most circumstances, is no. This current rating is the connector contact’s current limitation, i.e. the maximum current the connector contacts can withstand. Please note that current through the contacts shouldn’t exceed this maximum current rating even at very low voltages - you cannot undervolt a connector to get more current out of it. Doing so will cause the connector to melt or the contacts to weld, both of which will destroy your connector.